# how to join three tables and retrieve selected columns from the three tables and in oracle?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have 3 tables.
cinema, booking and customer

```
create table cinema
(
c_id int,
location varchar(10)
)
insert into cinema values(1,'New York');
insert into cinema values(2,'London');
insert into cinema values(3,'Paris');

create table booking
(
c_id int,
cust_id int
)

insert into booking values(1,10);
insert into booking values(2,11);
insert into booking values(3,12);
insert into booking values(3,13);
insert into booking values(2,14);

create table customer
(
cust_id int,
cust_name varchar(10)
)

insert into customer values(10,'sam');
insert into customer values(11,'adrian');
insert into customer values(12,'mark');
insert into customer values(13,'jim');
insert into customer values(14,'tom');
```

I want to select customer id(ie; cust_id), customer name(cust_name) and location(from cinema table) of all customer who have not booked in paris.

what i want is --

```
cust_id cust_name location
10      sam       New York   
11      adrian    London
14      tom       London
```

I tried a lot....
one of my code is ---

```
SELECT customer.cust_id,customer.cust_name,
cinema.location as Location FROM booking,cinema,customer
WHERE booking.c_id=cinema.c_id AND location!='Paris';
```

it gives me 15 result..
I cant think how to do this..
please help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you're not joining `booking` to `customer`, which is causing your problem. I use explicit joins as opposed to implicit here. Though there is no [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins), the explicit syntax is standard.

```
select cu.cust_id, cu.cust_name, ci.location
  from cinema ci
  join booking b
    on ci.c_id = b.c_id
  join customer cu
    on b.cust_id = cu.cust_id
 where ci.location <> 'Paris'
```

I'm not entirely certain about the structure of your booking table. I would expect a few more columns, for instance number of tickets, etc.

Comment: I was confused on multiple joins, but now its cleared. Thanks a lott.

Answer (score 3):

Your `WHERE statement` is not as specific as you want. 
You need a condition matching `booking.cust_id to customer.cust_id`:

```
WHERE booking.c_id = cinema.c_id 
AND booking.cust_id = customer.cust_id
AND location != 'Paris'
```

The way you are doing it now, you are geting results for all combinations of customers.

Answer (score 0):

See the below example :

```
Select   
businessuser.UserName,
businessuser.EmailAddress,
businessimages.ImgName, 
featured_cart.FeaturedPlan,featured_cart.StartDate
From featured_cart
Inner Join businessimages on featured_cart.FeaturedProId = businessimages.IdBusinessImages 
Inner Join businessuser  on businessimages.UserId = businessuser.IdBusinessUser
and featured_cart.FeaturedType = "Featured Email"
```

3 tables are :

1. businessuser
2. businessimages
3. featured_cart

this example work properly...

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server 2008:

```
select cust_id, cust_name, location
from customer c 
inner join booking b 
inner join location l
on c.cust_id = b.cust_id and b.c_id=l.c_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Compound Join Joining Four Tables:

**Used 4 Tables**

1. Customers
2. Orders
3. OrderDetails
4. Products

This Example works 100% You can try this in W3schools - Inner Join 'Try yourself' SQL Editor tables are taken from the W3schools Editor.

**QUERY:**

```
Select Customers.CustomerName as Table1_Customer, Orders.EmployeeID as Table2_Employee, OrderDetails.Quantity as Table3_OrderDetails,Products.ProductName as Table4_Products 
From Customers
INNER JOIN Orders 
ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails 
ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID 
INNER JOIN Products
ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID Order by EmployeeID;
```

Answer (score 0):

hii you can use join like this:

**SQL**

```
select customer.cust_id,customer.cust_name,cinema.location from cinema,customer,booking where cinema.c_id=booking.c_id and booking.cust_id=customer.cust_id and cinema.location not like 'paris';
```